# How to map NERDtree's bookmark

Tags: vim

Every time I want to bookmark something in NERDtree, I need to type `Bookmark <name>` in normal mode.

Is there some mapping that could make bookmarking more smoothly?

For example:

when I press `<leader><b>` in the NERDtree window, the command line shows `:Bookmark <name>`, all I need to do is fill the `<name>` and enter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
:autocmd Filetype nerdtree nnoremap <buffer> <leader>b :Bookmark
```

You need to have enabled filetypes using

```
:filetype plugin indent on
```

or similar.

Comment: :autocmd Filetype nerdtree nnoremap <buffer> <leader>b :Bookmark<space> would be better as I add some function to automatically remove the space at the trail of line